# rails 3 thinking-sphinx re-index failing

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.2, thinking-sphinx, postgresql-9.2

I've been hitting odd behaviours with thinking-sphinx indicies. The present state is that indexing is not occurring.

I am getting different behaviours with different commands. The cap deploy stalls under a rebuild sphinx command.

```
invoke_command "cd #{release_path} && RAILS_ENV=#{rails_env} bundle exec rake ts:rebuild"
```

The manual command to index

```
$ bundle exec rake ts:index --trace
** Invoke ts:index (first_time)
** Invoke environment (first_time)
** Execute environment
rake aborted!
FATAL:  sorry, too many clients already
/Users/me/app/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:1216:in `initialize'
```

Behaviour with a manual bundle exec rake ts:rebuild is a very long stall that I eventually interrupt.

Trying to stop the engine has a different error.  THere is a stall long enough to Ctrl-C and returns:

```
$ bundle exec rake ts:stop --trace
** Invoke ts:stop (first_time)
** Invoke environment (first_time)
** Execute environment
** Execute ts:stop
^Crake aborted!

/Users/me/app/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/thinking-sphinx-3.0.3/lib/thinking_sphinx/rake_interface.rb:56:in `sleep'
```

**Update**  wooops... I ran

```
bundle exec rake ts:index --trace
```

straight in terminal window on the server.  Indexed started writing. But got two warnings at the end.

> no process found by PID 82805
>
> indices NOT rotated

Does that paint a better picture?

** Update 2 **  data

```
   ??  S    11:28AM   0:06.93 /usr/local/bin/searchd --pidfile --config /Users/me/app/releases/20140127084810/config/development.sphinx.conf
   ??  S    11:28AM   0:00.00 /usr/local/bin/searchd --pidfile --config /Users/me/app/releases/20140127084810/config/development.sphinx.conf
   ??  S    13Jan14   1:16.68 /usr/local/bin/searchd --pidfile --config /Users/me/rails/releases/20140113100039/config/development.sphinx.conf
 s001  R+    1:23PM   0:00.00 grep searchd
```

For those interested, the issues got resolved via two discussions [one on settings](https://github.com/pat/thinking-sphinx/issues/722) and another on [identifying the processes and acting upon them](https://github.com/pat/thinking-sphinx/issues/723)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly - with Capistrano and Thinking Sphinx, it's now highly recommended that you set the generated Sphinx configuration file to live in the [shared directory](https://github.com/pat/thinking-sphinx/issues/497#issuecomment-31911515). This is probably why the rebuild cap task is hanging.

As for the warnings - can you confirm if the Sphinx daemon is running? `ps aux | grep searchd` should do the trick. If it is, it's worth checking that the pid file contains the right pid. If it's not running, then best to delete the pid file, as Sphinx/Thinking Sphinx is presuming otherwise.

Comment: First data point, sphinx.yml, thinking-sphinx.yml, development.sphinx.conf are all in shared/config/  It does appear to be running.  
For viewing convenience I've updated the result of ps aux | grep searchd. It references two applications with sphinx running, but two identical versions  of the same app I'm having issues with.  
Pid file states 57009; dunno what relationship that may bear.

Comment: The releases referred to for this app are NOT the latest.  There are two more recent ones.

Comment: You're using TS v3, so sphinx.yml is not referenced at all. thinking_sphinx.yml (note underscore) should be in your app's config directory, but should specify paths for your generated configuration file (e.g. production.sphinx.conf) and your index files and pid file so they live somewhere within the shared directory, with no symlinks required. See the first block of code on this page: http://pat.github.io/thinking-sphinx/deployment.html

Comment: And there will very likely be more than one searchd instance running (if it's running at all), as Sphinx uses threaded workers for TS v3.

Comment: Underscore, yes (my typo in the comment). thinking_sphinx.yml is in shared/config (app's config is symlinked to the shared directory) does point to shared/sphinx where the indicies lie.  However configuration_file and pid_file were not defined. production.sphinx.conf and development.sphinx.conf were in the shared/config so that seems to have gotten picked up.  I'll add those.  But searchd.pid - excuse my ignorance - does it get generated automatically on start?

Comment: The file gets generated automatically when the daemon starts - but best to have it in the shared directory, so it's not stored with a specific deploy.

Comment: Set pid_ and configuration_.  Out of curiosity, ran: bundle exec rake ts:stop --trace and got "searchd is not currently running.". Attempted a deploy and that failed with "bundle exec rake RAILS_ENV=development ts:configure" and rolled back.  The application *is* responding to sphinx queries, searchd log does not show a stop. So I surmise something is off between sphinx and thinking_sphinx confs. Have noticed double entries (relic from rails2 experience?): bin_path, searchd_file_path, use_64_bit and port. Acceptable? the t-s advanced_config page is not explicit enough for me...

Comment: Jerome: perhaps best to have this discussion in a GitHub issue at https://github.com/pat/thinking-sphinx/issues or via the Google group: https://groups.google.com/group/thinking-sphinx/

Comment: Yes just done so under github.  But I guess there are two issues, so I'll open a second